# Java ee http 404 tomcat

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat, jsf

Всем привет, у меня есть проблема в самом простом коде:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloResource {

   @GET
   public String hello() {
      return "Hello, World!";
     }
 }
```

Applcation:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class HelloApplication extends Application {

}
```

Конфигурация томката:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Applicatio]

Перехожу по ссылке: http://localhost:8888/api/hello
Вылетает ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В pom только одна зависимость:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Кто знает в чем проблема, подскажите

Comment: Зайдите в консоль tomcat и посмотрите, по какому пути ваше приложение исполняется. Сам путь до сервера `http://localhost:8888/` не означает, что приложение будет по этому пути развернуто. Скорее всего там будет имя артефакта посередине `http://localhost:8888/<artifact>/hello`

Comment: добавляю имя артефакта, но не помогает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ был достаточно простым, я прописал это в web.xml и это заработало. До этого я не трогал web.xml из-за того, что у меня работала аннотация WebServlet, что означало версию web.xml >3.0, а оказывается нет, после добавление этого, все заработало

```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
   </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Рад, что смогли разобраться. А логи без ошибок были? А то обычно там сразу пишется, что не задано имя для класса сервлета в web.xml.

Comment: Логи были без ошибок ,это было самое странное, как будто ошибки и не было. Знаете, когда я проходил дебагом и стучался по ссылке ,он просто не видел действий, получается, что стучался в никуда)